# Cannot find the ghost carriage return/line feed

Tags: php, html, regex, hexdump, hex-editors

I have a .php that file_get_contents of a openssl_pkcs7 signed and regex'd file, trimmed before echoing it for users to download.

However, the file downloaded has a line break/new line/carriage return at the top/start of the file which is breaking my subsequent code. The signed and regex'd template.mobileconfig doesn't have this empty line at the beginning of the file when I open it in notepad++/notepad but it's there when downloaded via a browser. I'm perplexed as to where it was inserted and even after trimming it, it is still there.

Code:

```
header("Content-type: text/plain");
header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=signed.mobileconfig");
$content = file_get_contents('./template.mobileconfig'); 
$trimmed = trim($content, " \t\n\r\0\x0B");
echo $trimmed;
```

The downloaded file looks like this in notepad/notepad++:

[image]

Line 1 is always empty. I've tried readfile() and trim() to try to work-around it but to no avail.

Output from hex editor online:

[image: Output of a hex editor:]

x0A apparently is a line feed but where is it coming from? Why didn't trim() get rid of it?

[image: Line Feed x0A]

Comment: Have you viewed the file in a hex editor to see what's actually in line 1?

Comment: Not yet! Thanks for pointing it out. Let me try and see what I get and I'll update here.

Comment: @ChrisR.Timmons Updated with output from Hex editor. x0A is a line feed. But where is it coming from? Why didn't trim remove it?

Comment: Just a guess, but it might be a side effect of the `echo` statement.  See the PHP manual entry for [trim](http://php.net/manual/en/function.trim.php), and scroll down to the comment by  "tongcheong77 at gmail dot com".  Maybe wrapping the call in PHP tags `<?php echo $trimmed;?>` would fix things.

Comment: can you post the mobileconfig file contents?

Comment: Case closed. Updated with solution.

Comment: Questions are for questions. Answers go in the answer section. That is, don't edit your question with the solution; either mark an existing answer as "accepted" or post a new answer with your solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is possible one of your `include()`s has a newline `\n`:

```
<?php
//code
?>     <======== \n right there (not visible)
```

Find all your included PHP files and remove spaces before the opening tag:

```
_
<?php
```

And get rid of the closing tag (not needed):

```
?>
```

Comment: HOLY SHIET. Thanks much. I went through all the included .php and noticed one of them had 2 line feeds after the '?>' tag. Removed them and the tag altogether and re-ran the code. Problem fixed!

Comment: I'm glad I could help :)

Comment: I strongly support the suggestion to just remove `?>`. If you don't have `?>` in your code, you never have to search for hidden newlines.

Answer (score 0):

What comes to my mind is trying to add x0A to your trim.

```
$trimmed = trim($content, " \t\n\r\0\x0B\x0A");
```

Comment: Tried your method, the line feed is still there! So frustrating :(